# Regex alphabetic only variable length positive/negative lookbehind

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Suppose that I have a text like below:

```
Lorem-Ipsum is simply dummy text of-the printing and typesetting industry. abc123-xyz 1abcc-xy-ef apple.pear-banana asdddd-abc-cba
```

I want to replace `-` with a whitespace if it is between alphabetic characters (letters) plus `-` (`[a-zA-Z-]`) until whitespace before/after. So, the result should be:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. abc123-xyz 1abcc-xy-ef apple.pear-banana asdddd abc cba
```

I tried:

`\b(?<=[a-zA-Z]+)\-(?=[a-zA-Z]+)\b`
This is not valid since lookbehind does not allow quantifiers, and I guess even if it worked it wouldn't cover all scenarios.

Is there a way to use variable length lookbehinds, or is there any other way for this case?

Edit: Using Python re library

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am using Python's re library

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)+(?!\S)', lambda x: x.group().replace('-', ' '), text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)+(?!\S)', lambda x: x.group().replace('-', ' '), text)
```

The regex matches whitespace-separated letter-only words with at least one `-` in them. Then, all hyphens are replaced with spaces inside the matches.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vibm7g/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - left-hand whitespace boundary
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)+` - one or more occurrences of a `-` char and then one or more ASCII letters
- `(?!\S)` - right-hand whitespace boundary.

Replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `[^\W\d_]` to match any Unicode letter words.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/d7KVIc):

```py
import re
text = r"Lorem-Ipsum is simply dummy text of-the printing and typesetting industry. abc123-xyz 1abcc-xy-ef apple.pear-banana asdddd-abc-cba"
print(re.sub(r'(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)+(?!\S)', lambda x: x.group().replace('-', ' '), text))
```

Output:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. abc123-xyz 1abcc-xy-ef apple.pear-banana asdddd abc cba
```

Comment: Thank you, so we can use negative lookbehind/lookahead to set a custom boundary, good to know!